# Select exists vs count

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlite-net-pcl

I am using Sqlite-net-pcl. I need to which query is better to use.
I am searching in a table if there is at least one record.

First query

```
Select exists(Select 1 from invnentory where itemname='box2')
```

Second query

```
Select count(*) from inventory where itemname='box2'
```

Both queries are working right. But which is the best approach to go for sqlite-net-pcl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
Select count(*) from inventory where itemname = 'box2'
```

normally must do a full table scan to return the number of rows that satisfy the condition in the `WHERE` clause.

But this:

```
Select exists(Select 1 from invnentory where itemname='box2')
```

will return as soon as it finds the 1st row that satisfies the condition and it will do a full table scan only if there isn't such a row.

So `EXISTS` should perform better.